# How does iExplorer obtain the phone number of an iPhone?

Tags: ios

Its not possible for an iOS app to programatically obtain the phone number.

But if you plug an iPhone into the iExplorer app it displays the number. How does it obtain it?

Comment: "Its not possible for an iOS app to programatically obtain the phone number." <- I think it is, just the way iExplorer and other desktop clients do it - talking to the lockdown daemon.

Comment: Wait a bit, I'll write an answer (in the meantime, you can google it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, it's possible both for iOS applications and for desktop (Windows and OS X) applications to retrieve the phone number (and other device-specific information, such as the IMEI, the serial number, etc.) from a particluar device by communicating to the lockdown daemon in iOS. The lockdown daemon (`lockdownd`) is a daemon process that runs on the device and provides access to these informations via Apple's proprietary API and protocol.

How all this works? For a desktop application, the developer has to link against the MobileDevice library (it's present by default on OS X and installed along with iTunes on Windows as far as I know) and use the functions in the reverse engineered header file ([here](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=MobileDevice_Library)) to obtain such data. For your information, on Linux, the same can be achieved by using [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/).

For an iOS app, the developer of the app has to link against `/usr/lib/liblockdownd.dylib` and import the corresponding (reverse engineered) header file, [`liblockdown.dylib`](https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks/blob/master/liblockdown.h), to use its functions.

Comment: Thanks. Presumably an iOS app doing that would be rejected from the app store.

Comment: @Piepants Yes. But see, I don't care about the AppStore, I'm a Cydia developer :)